# Bulk creation of In-App purchases or an alternative approach?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have been looking for a solution for a question for a while without any real luck.  Is there a way to bulk create non-consumable in-App purchases via iTunes Connect?  I have roughly 20,000 individual items within my app that can be unlocked via in-App purchase.

If there is not a bulk upload option, which I suspect there is not, is there a way to just place a single generic in-App purchase that will unlock a selected item?  For example I would present a table view with items available for unlocking based on user search criteria, each has a unique ID, with a button that would purchase that item that is selected.  All the items are the same price and of the same type.  Seems like this should work but I have not idea how to implement it with the in-App purchase confines.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that making 20.000 items in iTunes Connect isn't a right choice for you,
You can try to combine Apple's iAP with your server — just make several tiers of IAP(1$,2$,3$), each responsible for a variety of items with the same price, and on your server take track of what specific item have user purchase.

Because there is no default solution, provided by Apple, to make such kind of Store.

Comment: This is what I was thinking since they are all essentially the same item.  All that is happening is by making a purchase a flag is being reset within my app to activate the item.  I can easily keep track of the purchases with a plist uploaded to my servers with the buyers username.  The question is how do I name the in-App purchase item in iTunes?  Can I just call it "Unlock Selected Item" and be OK or does apple require a unique holder for every item I wish to unlock?

Comment: I know I'm late but note: apple has a limit of 10,000 per app so making a generic one is not only common sense but the only choice

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a way: uploading a csv(comma seperated values) text file, containing the products' metadata, and uploading it through Application Loader.

[Check This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451309/ios-how-i-can-load-multiple-in-app-items)

Quoting:

> You can use the Application Loader to mass import in app purchases: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf
>
> Read the "Creating a Package from a File" section on page 15:
>
> You can create a package containing the In-App Purchase you want to submit to iTunes by importing details from an Application Loader file and adding and editing the metadata. When creating a package from a file, be sure to use the Application Loader template. To get a copy of the template, choose File > Open App Import Template in Application Loader 2.9. Application Loader creates the AppFileImportTemplates folder containing the AppMassImportTemplate.txt template. To always have an original version of the template file, be sure to make a copy of the template before editing.

Regards