# iOS How I can load multiple in-app items

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-billing

Is there a way to load multiple items together on in-app billing section on itunes connect dashboard (for example with a .csv file like Android)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Application Loader to mass import in app purchases:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Read the "Creating a Package from a File" section on page 15:

> You can create a package containing the In-App Purchase you want to
>   submit to iTunes by importing details from an Application Loader file
>   and adding and editing the metadata. When creating a package from a
>   file, be sure to use the Application Loader template. To get a copy of
>   the template, choose File > Open App Import Template in Application
>   Loader 2.9. Application Loader creates the AppFileImportTemplates
>   folder containing the AppMassImportTemplate.txt template. To always
>   have an original version of the template file, be sure to make a copy
>   of the template before editing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I need also the screenshots for any item but I'm wondering what kind of image I have to use. A screenshot of single item? A screenshot of popup?

Comment: Usually a screenshot of how the user can buy the item is enough

Comment: Ok, for example I can submit a screenshot with a list of items, which each row is a couple of title-price text and a button to buy the item?

Comment: Yes. Also implement the "Restore purchases" functionality, I got rejected before for not having that in the app :)

Comment: Why I need the "Restore purchases" functionality? If I simply request the status at Apple server (bought- not bought) on demand when user clicks on single item, are there problems?

Comment: Hm, maybe that's enough, not sure. You can read about restoring here, if you don't already know that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9

Comment: Displayed name and description used for loading multiple items together on in-app billing section. Can anyone provide me with sample in mobile app where name and description we just uploaded will be displayed ?

Comment: Application loader no longer has the feature to upload a bulk, the button for import in the latest releases doesn't exist. Are there any alternatives?