# How can I use Application Loader to mass input In-App Purchases to iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, application-loader

I have 120+ IAP's to add. All very similar in a way. I've been told an application called Application Loader works off of JSON, and you can just enter 1 IAP, and then write a script to create all the remaining IAP's via JSON.

How can I do this? I've only opened Application Loader today and poked around a little bit.

Can anyone give a step-by-step detailed process?

Answer (score 3):

There are four steps to add multiple IAPs to iTunes Connect using the Application Loader (Version 3.0 at the time of writing):

- Open the Application Loader and access the template via the menu "File" --> "Open App Import Template". Copy the template somewhere else and open it with Excel or something similar.
- Add all your IAP Information and save the file as a .txt. (Leave the screenshot column empty.)
- Create a directory where you add screenshots for each IAP. The filename should match the product id of the IAP item. Example: "com.companyname.appname.productId.png".
- Use the import function of the Application Loader, where you will provide the .txt and will be asked for the screenshots.

If everything goes well your IAPs are now added and you can open iTunes Connect to submit them for review.

References:

- Stackoverflow similar question
  [iOS How I can load multiple in-app items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451309/ios-how-i-can-load-multiple-in-app-items)
- Instructions for adding multiple IAPs by Paperlit http://support.paperlit.com/entries/21684663-How-to-submit-multiple-iOS-In-App-Purchases
- "In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect" by Apple
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide.pdf
- "Using Application Loader" by Apple https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Comment: why there's no official txt example? for example if i want to add an auto-renewable subscription, how to set the duration in that txt file?

Comment: There is no file > open app import template in the application loader. I see no way in iTunes Connect to import any txt file.