# ERROR ITMS-5063: "Neither <provider> nor <team_id> is supplied - at least one is required" at Software

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am in the midst of cloning an iOS app - we are removing the original one from sale, and re-launching with a brand new App Id, etc.

Most of this is trivial, and the Dev Center + iTC stuff is mainly done, but I'd rather not type out all 30+ of my In App Purchases by hand again. I've been researching options on this, helped by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451309/ios-how-i-can-load-multiple-in-app-items),  and it seems that by using Application Loader, I have access to a mass import template, which I can add my SKU's, Product ID's, Price Tier's, etc.

So I've edited the txt file, and imported it into Application Loader, and that part works.... (see attached screenshot:)

[image: application loader - import success!!]

Now... when I try to deliver, I get the following error:

**ERROR ITMS-5063: “Neither  nor  is supplied - at least one is required” at Software**

[This PDF Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf) from Apple has no reference to this situation, and I can't find any more information...

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - by looking at the XML inside of the **.itmsp** package for both my new app and old app, I could see that within my old app, there was LOTS of other information, including leaderboards, screenshots, etc.

Part of that was the two tags `<provider>` and `<team_id>`, which were populated by my unique developer program id - the same one that shows up in  front of the managed Xcode Provisioning Profiles, etc. Pasting those two tags in-between the `<package>` and `<software>` tags at the start of the XML doc, I was able to successfully deliver the IAP's to ITC. Yay!